# Django celery crontab not working when CELERY_TIMEZONE='Asia/Calcutta'

Tags: django, celery

I am tyring to schedule a task in Django using celery.Everything works fine when the CELERY_TIMEZONE='UTC' but doesnt work when I change the CELERY_TIMEZONE='Asia/Calcutta'.

```
#settings.py
CELERY_TIMEZONE='UTC'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

#tasks.py
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(day_of_month="1-31", hour=6, minute=8), name="newtask1")
def elast():
        print "test"
```

This works just fine but when I change my settings to

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE='Asia/Calcutta'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False

#tasks.py
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(day_of_month="1-31", hour=11, minute=38), name="newtask1")
def elast():
        print "test"
```

This doesn't work.I can't seem to figure out the issue.Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fixed by updating the celery version to 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Configure Celery to use a custom time zone. The timezone value can be any time zone supported by the pytz library.

kindly refer this [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#timezone) reference guide